# Export animation to movie

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am creating effects in my AIR application using actionscript like fadeIn and fadeOut. is there any way to export those animation to movie format like FLV or AVI using actionscript?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's going to be any way to do this on the web unless you stream the data to some sort of server like Red5 or Flash Media Server or something along those lines. If you're just looking to capture the effects and can build/run the app as an AIR app you can probably use the class found here http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/assets_code/SimpleFlvWriter.as.txt to get it to save the data to a file.  You can use (can't post multiple links damn stackoverflow for not linking my accounts correctly...) google "BitmapData draw flex reference"
in order to draw the stage to a bitmapdata object then you'd have to push that data into the SimpleFlvWriter.as (not as simple as it sounds :) ), sorry don't know of a boxed solution for this let me know if you're able to make anything of it and good luck!  oh also as an aside you may be able to get away with just using something like SnagIt depending on the fidelity you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, I successfully create flv file using simpleflvwriter. Now next point is how to import effects in it.